# BixData or Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, debian-lenny, zabbix

I've been using Ganglia to monitor my single Mac OSX server which runs Apache and MySQL. I'm ok with it.

Now we are upgrading our servers, 6 IBM X3650 M3 and 2 Fujitsu servers.
2 IBM for Apache cluster and 4 IBM for MySQL NDB Cluster. The other two servers are for Load balancers.

All servers are going to run Debian Lenny 5 on it.

Now I need to decide on which monitoring tool I should go for. I found that BixData and Zabbix does an excellent job than Ganglia, in terms of sensors and reporting.

Have anyone tried the above two tools? And which tool would you suggest me? For Debian.
As I'm writing this, I'm installing BixData to try....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian, there should be fairly up to date packages of Zabbix available - Debian maintainers are doing a good job.
If you would prefer compiling from source, that should be fairly trivial as well.

Or, if you would like something even more simple, try the Zabbix virtual appliance which will allow you to play with latest version without risk of breaking something. Once you try out some monitoring options with it, continue with local setup.

Comment: I tried zabbix. It's very comprehensive. It satisfy my needs. And I prefer compiling from source. Cos, debian lenny repository doesn't t have the latest stable version of zabbix.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Zabbix but haven't tried BixData. I would recommend trying Zenoss as well, better than zabbix if you ask me.

Comment: I can see a lot of people recommend Zenoss.. I think I should try Zenoss too. I just tried Zabbix, seems like too many customization options... Thanks for the recommendation...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't Use Bixdata if you ask me use Zabbix

Comment: zabbix is supper product from open source

Comment: I agree with this!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [bixdata.com](http://bixdata.com/):

> BixData is a comprehensive management solution for new, dynamic IT infrastructures being built with mixed virtualization. Bix's platform represents a profound innovation in management science, uniquely suited to the complex demands of this technology. Our breakthrough p2p architecture condenses a full-feature management suite into a single streamlined, self-installing package.

I see a lot of buzzwords on there, but no clear explanation of what it does or how.  If the quality of their marketing is a reflection of their documentation, then I'd steer clear.

There are a ton of monitoring systems out there though.  You are a small shop at the moment, so go for one that doesn't require a whole bunch of additional infrastructure to run, and doesn't require you to fully understand the system before you can start using it.

If there is only one person doing the monitoring from a single computer, and you don't require 24/7 alerting, you might get away with something like [Quest's pt360](http://www.packettrap.com/product/pt360_pro.aspx), which will install on a Windows desktop or server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this useful page about lots of monitoring tools:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_monitoring_comparison

Anyway, I use the zabbix frotend of Nagios for servers but I think Centreon (http://www.centreon.com/) is worth taking a look :)

Comment: not sure what exactly "zabbix frotend of Nagios" was supposed to mean, but zabbix is not a nagios frontend :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you ask me, I will say: Use Zabbix.  I tried several network monitors in the paste, and choose Zabbix for 3 reasons:

1 - Improve performance release after release.

2 - Scales well. I had a  setup with 6k monitored servers without one single item in queue for more than 30 seconds.

3 - It's easy to setup, mantain and customize alerts and checks.